# Numeros Abundantes Impares del 1 al 1000

Tags: c++

Necesito poder determinar que números del 1 al 1000 son impares abundantes, soy nuevo en esto y esto es lo que hice, no se la verdad que problemas podría tener y mi sintaxis tampoco es tan buena  :(

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, aux=0;
    for(n=1; n<=5; n++)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                aux=aux+i;
                if(aux>n && n&2!=0)
                {
                    cout<<"El numero impar "<< n <<" es abundante"<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que es un numero abundante, y cual seria el problema de este codigo?

Comment: No puedes detectar si un número es abundante si no haces ninguna comprobación al respecto.